# Can't save custom system config value

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to simply save my configuration settings in the backend. I have created a grouped section with 3 entities, enabled, minimum_cart_amount and coupon_amount.

system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <vendortab translate="label" module="vendor_newsletter">
            <label>Vendor</label>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        </vendortab>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <vendor translate="label" module="vendor_newsletter">
            <tab>vendortab</tab>
            <label>Settings</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <newsletter translate="label" module="vendor_newsletter">
                    <label>Newsletter</label>
                    <tab>vendor</tab>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment><![CDATA[Enable this extension]]></comment>
                        </enabled>
                        <coupon_amount translate="label">
                            <label>Coupon Amount</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment><![CDATA[Amount of the coupon that customers receive after they have subscribed completely.]]></comment>
                        </coupon_amount>
                        <minimum_cart_amount translate="label">
                            <label>Minimum Cart Amount</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment><![CDATA[Minimum cart amount for newly generated coupons. Does not affect existing coupons.]]></comment>
                        </minimum_cart_amount>
                    </fields>
                </newsletter>
            </groups>
        </vendor>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Also I have setup a default node in my `config.xml` to set defaults for those.

I receive the 404 not found page in backend when trying to save these. Is there anything wrong regarding naming conventions?

The nodes are viewable in the backend and with `config.xml` default nodes I'm able to pre-set them and use them in the code later.

Comment: Have you tried to sign out and sign-in again in the admin panel?

Comment: @arjus yes, several times.